# The cosine equations for two problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. Piston Problem: A piston in an automobile engine goes up and down inside the cylinder as shown in Figure 4-8b, causing the crankshaft to rotate. Suppose that at time =0.1 seconds the piston is at its maximum distance from the top of the cylinder, y=13 cm. The crankshaft has a radius of 6 cm and makes one revolution every 0.5 seconds.

[image]
Write an equation for the situation above.

I want to write the equation in terms of cosine. 
y=C+AcosB(x-D)

This is my equation:y=7+1cos0.5(x-0). I have a feeling that this is wrong. Could someone help clarify this question for me please and give the equation?

2.Spaceship Problem. A spacecraft is in an elliptical orbit around the earth (Figure 4-8c). At time t=0 hours, it is at its apogee (highest point) d=1000 km above the earth's surface. It is at its perigee d=100km above the surface 50 minutes later. 
[image]

Write an equation for the situation above.

I also want to write the equation in terms of cosine
y=C+AcosB(x-D)

y=550+1cos50(x-0). This is my equation. I am pretty sure this is wrong. Could someone help me derive the right equation and tell me how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the maximum value of y?
What minimum values of y?
What is the midpoint?
What is the amplitude?

Answering these questions will give you the answers for A and C above.

Are we starting at the maximum or the minimum?

This will give you the sign of A.  If we start at the maximum the sign of A is positive.  If we start at the minimum the sign is negative.

What is the frequency and the period of this motion.  This will give you the value of B.

For what value of $t$ are we at the maximum?  This will give us the value of -D.

max 13.
min 1.
Amplitude $=\frac {\text {max} - \text {min}}{2}= 6.$
Midpoint $=\frac {\text {max} + \text {min}}{2}= 7.$
Period = $0.5$ s
Frequency $= \frac {2\pi}{\text {period}} = 4\pi$
Phase shift $= 0.1$ s

Until you are very comfortable doing these, fill out this table every time.

$y = 7 + 6\cos 4\pi(t-0.1)$

b)

Max = 1000
Min = 100
Amplitude = 450
Midpoint 550

Period -- it completes $\frac 12$ revloution in 50 minutes.  100 min
frequency $\frac {\pi}{50}$

Phase shift $= 0$  We are starting at the maximum.

$d = 550 + 450\cos \frac {\pi}{50} t$